# Online resource to get|find a list of available packages in Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management

I am creating a Docker image on top of the default one for [PHP-FPM](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/173945670390f6595da8f93ae46b442167ff05be/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile) by running the following command on the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get update \ && 
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install php7.1-memcached \
    php7.1-mysql \
    php7.1-gd \
    php7.1-mbstring \
    php7.1-mongodb \
    php7.1-intl php7.1-xdebug \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

Some of the extensions was non installed maybe because didn't exists. If I try `apt-cache search php71` inside the container I got a list of what I have installed but not a list of what is available on the repository.

Is there any online tool or place where I can find what packages are available already for this version of PHP?

Comment: Don't delete `apt/lists/*`, then you'll have a working `apt-cache search` command.

Answer (score 3):

That Dockerfile isn't installing PHP from packages, it's building it from the source. You won't find anything as a package, you need to change the `configure` options in the main Dockerfile and/or add your own compilation instructions...

Comment: Change the configure options to what?

Comment: [PHP](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/173945670390f6595da8f93ae46b442167ff05be/7.1/fpm/Dockerfile#L100).